# non-recursive predictive table-driven LL(1) parser in functional programming

Tags: parsing, functional-programming, ll-grammar, non-recursive

I want to know which is the best way to build a non-recursive predictive table-driven LL(1) parser in functional programming: Hand-coding in Haskell or OCaML or does it exist a tool that can help me with this?

Comment: You can also check [LL(1) parser generator in OCaml](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8070511/ll1-parser-generator-in-ocaml).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Are there any LL Parser Generators for Functional Languages such as Haskell or Scala?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5507665/are-there-any-ll-parser-generators-for-functional-languages-such-as-haskell-or-s)

Answer (score 0):

There are Haskell bindings for ANTLR, a LL(*) parser generator.

Ses also [Are there any LL Parser Generators for Functional Languages such as Haskell or Scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5507665/are-there-any-ll-parser-generators-for-functional-languages-such-as-haskell-or-s).